# Avoid pagebreaks after group titles in glossary

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I am using my own glossary style which is simply an updated version of the existing stlye `altlistgroup`. The problem is, that I can run into a pagebreak right between a group heading and the first entry of the group. How can I avoid this?

The only flag I found was `\glsgroupskip` but this seems to handle only the skip between groups and not between the heading of a group and its first entry.

Here is my style definition so far:

```latex
\newglossarystyle{thesislist}{%
\setglossarystyle{altlistgroup}%
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
    \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}]%
    \mbox{}\newline\nobreak\@afterheading
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2}%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    \item[\glslistgroupheaderfmt{\glsgetgrouptitle{\Large\color{red!40}##1}}]}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we can fix it with the same solution as for avoiding page breaks between entries and their descriptions. The following does the trick for me:

```tex
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    \item[\glslistgroupheaderfmt{\glsgetgrouptitle{\Large\color{red!40}##1}}]}
    \mbox{}\nopagebreak\@afterheading
}
```

A similar fix is described in the glossaries manual on p.282: [Glossaries User Manual (v. 4.46)](https://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-code.pdf) but only for glossary entries and not for headings.